# Unable to remove testflight sdk from my App

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, testflight

I had included the testflight sdk in my app but then decided to remove it. I have removed the library, and al references to it in my Xcode project. Now, when I run the app on my iPad from xcode, the app that gets installed on my iPad is testflight free. However, when I create an ipa and transfer it to my iPad, it contains the testflight sdk and the console log says testflight session started on every launch.

I have delete all kinds of caches and have done this a few dozen times over, but can't remove Testflight from my SDK. Anyone know which caches might be responsible for this?

Comment: clean+build while in any scheme that uses the `Release` profile. CMD+SHIFT+K to clean, or use the menus.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I have done clean, option+clean (essentially cmd+shift+k), deleted derived data, reset simulator content and settings, removed .xcu file from my project's package contents, and nothing has helped. What do you mean when you say "while in any scheme that uses the Release profile"?

Answer (score 2):

Try to 'move to trash' the whole library files.